# Remove shipping fee from existing order

Tags: shipping

Is it possible somehow to remove shipping fee from existing order? I tried to edit the order, but i have an error message after i clicked on the edit button: "Please specify the product's option(s)."

Answer (score 0):

No its not possible because the data will be stored in many tables if you try to edit it will lead to an error.

Comment: Thanks Ravichandra for you quick response. Isn't there any solution for this? I think it is normal situation, if somebody order twice and he would like to pay just one shipping fee if we ship these orders in one packege.

Comment: I found one solution, but it is not the nicest. I create invoice for both order, but for one i create a credit memo and delete the shipping fee. Maybe there should be a solution for this without create these 2 invoice and after modify them with credit memo.

Comment: HI i got an idea i don't know does it suits but it meets your requirement i think so here it goes, First you need to fetch the invoice id from invoice you need to fetch the products, once you have products which already placed then what you can do is you can compare the new order with old order , if the user ordering same product twice then dont apply shipping method else apply shipping method.